# From where I can get phonemes in audio format?

Tags: phonemes, speech-recognition

I am working on a speech recognition system and to begin with I need all phonemes of English in audio format by which I will be able to compare with my speech fragments.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might want to show some research effort first, it'll increase the chances that others are willing to help you ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing. What can be recorded (i.e. what occurs in speech) is an allophone, and phonemes are abstractions built from allophones. Every allophone occurs in a particular context, so the acoustic value of /k/ in "keep" is different from the value of /k/ in "cool". Allophones also do not have well-defined acoustic beginning and ending points; for example the acoustic properties of [t] in "bat" extend backwards into the vowel [æ] so that one can (somewhat) identify "bat" as distinct from "bad" before reaching the consonant [t]/[d].